# Remove infopath and use powerapps form instead

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, powerapps-forms

I have a list where we keep client info that i'd imported to sharepoint online from a sharepoint 2010 server. I'd like to use PowerApps to customize the form but the option isn't available. When I go to List Settings-->Form Settings, the only option is "Customize the current form using Microsoft InfoPath."  How do i get rid of the old infopath form and use PowerApps instead?

I've tried using powershell to set the _ipfs_infopathenabled property to false. I've deleted the template.xsn file from the folder along with the forms from the ContentType resourceFolder, but nothing seems to have changed in the list settings.

I'd prefer not to have to delete and recreate the list as it's used in a bunch of lookups throughout the rest of the site and I'm concerned that it will mess those up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/customize-list-form) note:

[image]

If PowerApps option is not listed, it should be your list contains data types that PowerApps doesn't support.

You can refer to the known issues:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/connections/connection-sharepoint-online#known-issues

For your issue, I am afraid you need to recreate your list to use PowerApps form.

===================================
If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.

Comment: Sigh! I was afraid of that. Thanks for the article